# linearly reductive group acting on $X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $k$ and $G$ a linearly reductive group $G$ acting on $X$. Under what assumptions on $k$ or $G$ we have $\mathrm{Ext}^i_G(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})\simeq \mathrm{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})^G$ ?

Comment: What are $\mathcal{F}$,$\mathcal{G}$ ?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves.

Comment: Then, this holds. You just derive the formula for $i=0$ using (for instance) Grothendieck's spectral sequence for the derived functors of a composite functor, and the fact that $(\cdot)^G$ is exact. There is an elementary direct proof of course.

Comment: So it is the same argument as for finite groups...